# Can standard hosting (not vps) be made into a torrent's client?

Tags: php, client

Is it possible to force the server to download files from peer-to-peer networks just like human can download files using - for example - utorrent? Can it be done using php? Any thoughts? Did anyone try doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is most likely not possible unless they give you SSH/shell access to the server. Even  if they do, it is very unlikely a shared host provider would let you continue running such a long-living bandwidth-consuming application.

The reason a torrent client cannot be implemented a straight PHP web-script is that wbe servers are designed for short-lived script runs (that only execute while a http client (browser) is connected). Most PHP configurations on shared hosts will have a time-limit for script executions that will eventually kill the process. It is also very likely that the PHP configuration will prevent making socket connections to arbitrary external ports. Otherwise, there is nothing preventing a torrent client from being implemented in the PHP language.

If you want more control, find a cheap VPS provider. Although, be aware, many still may have terms of use banning torrent clients and the like.